# Traversing a diagram that represents real operations

Tags: python, graph, diagram

Greetings,

Can anyone please tell me what algorithm is used for traversing a directed acyclic graph/ diagram like this :

> Ex.
>   Diagram nodes : A, B, C, D1, D2, D3, E
>   Diagram edges : A → B,  B → C,  C → D1,  C → D2,  C → D3,  D1 → E,  D2 → E, D3 → E

The traversal is like this :

> A → B → C → D1, then C → D2, then C → D3,
>   And after that, they join : D1 → E, D2 → E, D3 → E

My graph represents real time operations. Most operations are linear, but when operations split on condition, each split (ex. node C splits to D1, D2 and D3) waits for all operations to finish before they join again (ex. nodes D1, D2 and D3 join at node E)

I need to iter over my nodes and call each operation in this exact order.

I use Python with pygraph, but you can use any language if you want to post some algorithm.

Maybe it's a standard name for this algorithm, like Depth-first search, Dijkstra's algorithm, Hill climbing, i don't know ?...

Thank you very very much !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [topological sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) will give you the order that you need to perform the operations in given the edges.

Comment: Great ! I used topological sort and node neighbors to create all the edges, like i wanted ! Thank you !